# processing multiple directories each containing multiple files in R

Tags: r, excel, csv, directory

I am processing each files in a particular directory using

```
files=list.files(path_of_directory, recursive=T, pattern='.xlsx')
for(i in 1:length(files))  
{
#Some processing takes places which takes all files in a particular directory
and produces single file
}
```

The code that was used for the final output (after processing all files in a directory):

```
write.xlsx(datasetr_df, file = file.path("Out_Put_Dir_Path", paste0("Manually_writting_name_output_name_same_as_Input_Dir",".xlsx")),sheetName="Sheet1",col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
```

Each time I changes the path of the directory to process the files it contains and also I used to change the name of single output file on the basis of directory processed. Suppose the directory being D1, D2 and D3, each containing the files F1 and F2. Is there any way which further automates this process. The program performs the following steps:
1. Ist moves to a particular directory
2. Processes all files in that directory and the final sinle file is given the same name as of directory. 
3. Moves to next directory
4. Process all files in this next directory and the final single file is given the same name as of directory. 
5.This process goes on till all directories and the contained files are processed.
6. So if there are five directories, 5 excel files are generated. Now suppose D1 directory is processes, I should get the output as D1 processed. It would be of great help if one can help in writing the code for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest your loop in 2 levels such that level one cycles through directories and level two though files in each directory. Consider this:

```
#List all dirs you need to process
dlist <- list.dirs("parent_dir") #parent dir==main dir with all the dirs

#Loop over dirs
for(d in dir_list){

    #List files in d'th dir that need to be processed
    flist <- list.files(d, pattern='.xlsx')

    #Loop over files
    for(f in flist){

        #Some processing takes places here
    }

#Write output
write.xlsx(datasetr_df, file=paste0(d,".xlsx"), 
sheetName="Sheet1",col.names=T, row.names=F)

#Report progress
print(paste0("Finished processing directory ", d))

}
```

Comment: @Shekeine..many thanks for the help...I am trying to list all the directories in parent directory using   dlist <- list.dirs("Parent_dir_path",recursive=FALSE) , but it is not showing me the list of directories it contains when I type dlist in console..it shows dlist character(0).

Comment: Replace `Parent_dir_path` by the actual path of the parent directory. For example, list.dirs("shekeine/rstats/mydata") where `mydata` is the folder containing the directories with the files I want to process. Also, check that the path is specified correctly (i.e., exists)..

Comment: @Shekeine..many thanks for the help...It works now..can you also help in naming the processed file on the basis name of directory it process each time. Earlier I am doing it each time manually.

Comment: Are you writing out your results after `#Some processing takes places here`? Could you post the line that writes out your result?

Comment: @Shekeine..many thanks for the prompt replies..I have written the lines of code which writes output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89206/discussion-between-gaurav-kumar-and-shekeine).

Answer (score 2):

You can continue with the same logic. For example, Wrapping your processing in a function that you call it for each directory.

```
lapply(list("path_d1","path_d2"),  ## add list of directory here
    function(path_of_directory){
          files=list.files(path_of_directory, 
                       recursive=TRUE, pattern='.xlsx')
          lapply(files ,function(file){ ## better to use lapply here than for loop
          ## Some processing takes places 
          ## which takes all files in a particular directory
          ## and produces single file
     })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

do it like this

```
lapply(list.dirs("path",recursive = F),function(dir)  
{lapply(list.files(dir),function(file){read.csv(file)})})
```

This uses `lapply` in chain.

First it finds all the directory then applies a function to each directory. This inner function list all the files in that directory and applies a function that reads the csv files.

This is my custom function for reading the files. For your implementation just replace the inner function with your function that you have written say `myfunction` to process a single file like this and use this statement.

```
lapply(list.dirs("path",recursive = F),function(dir) {lapply(list.files(dir),myfunction)})
```

Comment: ..Many thanks for the answer. Can you please also explain how you are naming your output dynamically one by one (Please refer to questions for more)

Comment: can you please explain what kind of output you are expecting. in your myfunction you will get your file one by one in each directory recursively. you can do some processing on it and write that file with the file name you wish. for example if I receive any file with name "filename" i will append "processed" word and write that file. This logic will work for all the files.

Comment: @gauravkumar the question does not show any effort that you have done for problem even though giving the complete solution in detail your asking for complete code which is not correct. if there are further questions you should post a new question and accept the answer to this question of yours.